# Angular 11, Typescript, Nodejs, mysql - If email domain correct on register component, show button based on 'mysql' Boolean value, in home component

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript, boolean

Currently trying to add functionality in my application that would check for a certain domain email address during registration, and based on this, the user will see a specific button on the 'home' page later. (Something like; If @hotmail.com email, patchValue('1'). Then If '0', hide button, if '1', show button.)

The email 'check' is done in my 'isTestEmail' function, in the 'register.component.ts' and the check is working correctly based on my console.log output.

Next, in the same function, I want to then set a value (isLecturer) in the accounts DB table, from '0' to '1' if the desired email address was entered.

Then in my 'home.component.html', show or hide a specific button (using ngIf), based on that mySQL account table property (isLecturer) value of 0 or 1 (true/false).

My problem is that I am unsure of the correct syntax to put in my 'isTestEmail' function, that will change the value in the database, from 0 to 1.

I'm also unsure of what code to add in the 'lab-swap-home.component.ts', to assist the detection of the NgIf statement in the 'lab-swap-home.component.html'.

I'm not confident in my proposed solution and could be overthinking this. I would love to see any easier suggestions to implement this functionality.

Database > Accounts table > isLecturer config:

[image]

register.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AccountService, AlertService } from '@app/_services';
import { MustMatch } from '@app/_helpers';
import { Account } from '@app/_models/account';  //

@Component({ templateUrl: 'register.component.html' })
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    email: any;
    //isLecturer: boolean = true; //optional way, unsure.
    //isLecturer: any;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private alertService: AlertService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            firstName: ['', Validators.required],
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
            confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
            acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
            //isLecturer: ['', Validators.required],
        }, {
            validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')
        });
    }

    public TestFunc() {
        console.log('Function is called')    
    }

    public isTestEmail() { 
        // var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        // if(re.test(email)){
            //Email valid. Procees to test if it's from the right domain (Second argument is to check that the string ENDS with this domain, and that it doesn't just contain it)
            if(this.form.controls.email.value.indexOf("@hotmail.com", this.form.controls.email.value.length - "@hotmail.com".length) !== -1){
                //VALID
                console.log("TEST EMAIL VALID");
                this.isLecturer.patchValue('1'); // Intended way.
                this.isLecturer = false; // optional way, unsure how to implement.
            }
            else{
                console.log("TEST EMAIL INVALID");
            }

        //}
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.form.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        console.log('LOOK!')
        this.TestFunc(); // calling function this way works!
        this.isTestEmail();

        //this.accountService.isTestEmail
        //this.accountService.TestFunc

        // reset alerts on submit
        this.alertService.clear();

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.form.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.accountService.register(this.form.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe({
                next: () => {
                    this.alertService.success('Registration successful, please check your email for verification instructions', { keepAfterRouteChange: true });
                    this.router.navigate(['../login'], { relativeTo: this.route });
                },
                error: error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

(model) account.ts:

```
import { Role } from './role';

export class Account {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    role: Role;
    jwtToken?: string;
    isLecturer?: boolean;
}
```

lab-swap-home.component.html button example:

```
<button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-1')" *ngIf="isLecturer === '1'" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mb-3 ml-3" >Create available lab slots</button>
```

account.model.js (backend):

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = model;

function model(sequelize) {
    const attributes = {
        email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        passwordHash: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        acceptTerms: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN },
        isLecturer: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN },
        isStudent: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN },
        role: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        verificationToken: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
        verified: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        resetToken: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
        resetTokenExpires: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        passwordReset: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        created: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW },
        updated: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        isVerified: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            get() { return !!(this.verified || this.passwordReset); }
        }
    };

    const options = {
        // disable default timestamp fields (createdAt and updatedAt)
        timestamps: false, 
        defaultScope: {
            // exclude password hash by default
            attributes: { exclude: ['passwordHash'] }
        },
        scopes: {
            // include hash with this scope
            withHash: { attributes: {}, }
        }        
    };

    return sequelize.define('account', attributes, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe to have resolved my own issue by moving the 'isTestEmail' function into the 'home' component, and checking the current users account email, by calling the function during page initialization. Then the button is hidden / shown based on the current users email domain.

Managed to get the correct syntax, In html:

```
*ngIf="isLecturer === true"
```

And home.component.ts:

```
isLecturer: boolean = false
```

```
public isTestEmail() { 
            if(this.account.email.indexOf("@mail.com", this.account.email.length - "@mail.com".length) !== -1){
                this.isLecturer = true;
            }
            else{
                console.log("TEST EMAIL INVALID");
            }

        //}
    }
```